# Smooth my own object

Tags: modeling

I try to smooth my simple objetc.
[image]

My first idea was the Sub Mod, but when I add it, my object is going to destroy. According YT, you have to add loops but how can I add loops on this object? Next tip was "Mark Sharp" and Auto Smooth but this did't work as well...So is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're right with the subdivision surface modifier - just inset the top and bottom faces slightly. To keep the edge relatively sharp, you might want to add an edge loop (or 2) around the circumference as well.

[image: InsetLoop]

Comment: Have you bevel the edges and add Insert Face?

Comment: I didn't bevel anything. I just made a shape like yours, selected the top and bottom faces and inset them. I then added 2 loop cuts around the middle edge and spaced them out equally.